# Run Pipeline on single maven module

Tags: maven, bitbucket-pipelines

I have the following requirement: Run Bitbucket Pipeline to release jar of a single Maven module in a multimodules structure. Is that possible?

My setup:
We have multimodules library (parent-pom + submodules) and each submodule have its own independent version.

Let's assume we need to fix a bug in one of the modules so I would like to create a new branch, fix the bug and release only this specific module which means update its version and deploy it to our server.

We are new to Maven multimodules with unique versions, but I image from terminal I would go to the specific module folder and run maven release plugin with deploy...

How do I do it from Bitbucket using pipeline and stages...is that even possible?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You can still specify the module over which you are executing a plugin / goal with `-pl` switch. Meanwhile, you would still need to update the whole project version assuming the sub-modules are following the parent module version.

Comment: so, for example, if I have moduleA and moduleB and I would like to release only moduleB from BB, then I would need to put a custom stage in the `pipelines.yml` file specific for the module which will use the `-pl` switch. I'm I on point?